# Animate Circular thumbnail size grow on mouse over using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have generated circular thumbnail of images using Css3 border-radius. I want mouseover animation where circle thumbnails dimension grow on mouse hover and return to original dimension on mouse out.And dimension increases from center of circle with overlapping left and right thumbnail of that circle.

css:

```
 #baar{position:fixed;width:100%;height:110px;background:black;top:130px;}

    ul#block{ display:inline-block; list-style:none; position:relative;left:0px;}

    ul#block li{float:left; list-style:none;width:110px; height:110px;overflow:visible; position:relative; text-align:center;padding-left:5px}

    ul#block li img {background:grey;width:100px; height:100px;border :5px solid red;border-radius:55px 55px 55px 55px;}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="baar">
    <ul id="block">
        <li><img></li>   
         <li><img></li> 
         <li><img></li> 
         <li><img></li> 
    </ul>    
</div>
</body>
```

and this the jquery I have which gives me animation of dimension grow but circle doesn't remains on initial center . width increase toward right and height increase toward bottom.

```
$("ul#block li img").mouseover(function() {
$(this).animate({'width':130, 'height':130}, {duration:100});
                    }).mouseout(function(){

$(this).animate({'width':110, 'height':110}, {duration:100});
                    });
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k9nQU/15/

So help me write proper jquery for animation where circle grow up keeping center as it is and overlap aside thumbnail during animation period.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3:

```
ul#block li img {
    background:grey;
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    border :5px solid red;
    border-radius: 55px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
}
ul#block li img:hover {
    width:120px; 
    height:120px;
    left: -10px;
    top: -10px;
    border-radius: 65px;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul#block li img').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '120px',
        height: '120px',
        left: '-10px',
        top: '-10px',
        borderRadius: '65px'
    }, 100);
});
$('ul#block li img').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
        left: '0px',
        top: '0px',
        borderRadius: '55px'
    }, 100);
});
```

And remember to add 'position: relative' for those imgs!

Comment: Is there any way to grab this animation if css set for responsive design using css3 media queries.

Comment: I dont understand the question :(

Comment: All dimension values are set here for specific resolution only, may be for mobile screen circle dimension changes in responsive design. so we need to animate width, left.left ,top using variable to get the same effect in any screen resolution.

Comment: Well, if you want it made by jQuery, you just have to count new values.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is by using CSS3's transitions + transforms.

```
div {
    background: hotpink;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms;
    transition: transform 250ms;
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

If you really need to do it with jQuery then you'll need to play with the position of the element in addition to its width/height.

Comment: Yeah I need to adjust position also to get proper smooth animation